# Manage git repo using custom remote origin

Tags: git, git-remote

We have a codebase which is internal to our company - so we can't check in code to a github account for example. Is it possible to instead configure the remote origin to point to a designated server? That server would be within the company's VPC and would be where you push a commit. How would that server need to be configured? I tried searching online but most of the results I got were around switching remote origins between bitbucket/github.

Comment: You can set up multiple _remotes_ in a single local repo so you can interact with them. Check `git help remote`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+remotes